# Uncaught ReferenceError: r is not defined - react redux webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

I'm learning React with Redux and Webpack but I keep getting

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: r is not defined
```

It always stops at exactly this point in bundle.js:

```
    _reactDom2.default.render(_react2.default.createElement(
  _reactRedux.Provider,
  { store: createStoreWithMiddleware(_reducers2.default) },
  _react2.default.createElement(_reactRouter.Router, { history: _reactRouter.browserHistory, routes: _routes2.default })
), document.getElementById('app'));
r;
```

highlighting the r; on the last line.  I've searched everywhere and am stumped.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post your code? are you sure you don't have a random `r` somewhere?

Comment: I went carefully through all my code and sure enough -- there was an errant r some where!  Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you mark that as an answer and accept it?